# How to import and export VCard file using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, contacts, vcf-vcard

I'm new to swift .I’m having problem while exporting contact from iPhone and to convert it into .Vcf file for uploading file into Web server. Furthermore, I want to import .Vcf file from Web server and convert into iPhones contacts’ pattern. Can anyone please help me in achieving the desired result ?.

Comment: Did you attempt anything? Like writing `VCard` in XCode documentation that should leads you to `CNContactVCardSerialization` (which is a good start). Then, Upload/Download it is another question and there are plenty of question about that. In other words: Your question is too broad and lack some research or attempts.

Answer (score 5):

Please try the following code snippet.

```
public func processContacts() throws {

        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        let status = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)


        switch status {
        case .denied:
            throw ContactAccessError(description: "Access Denied")
        case .notDetermined:
            // In case of not determined request for access
            // If allowed it will return success otherwise return error
            contactStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler:{ success, error in
                if success {

                    print("Access Allowed")
                    var contacts = [CNContact]()
                    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactIdentifierKey as NSString, CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)])
                    do {
                        try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, stop in
                            contacts.append(contact)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    for contact in contacts{
                        do{
                            var data = Data()
                            try data = CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])
                            let fileManager = FileManager.default
                            do {
                                let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
                                let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("someName").appendingPathExtension("vcf")
                                try data.write(to: fileURL)
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }catch{
                            print("Some Error")
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    class ContactAccessError: LocalizedError {

        private var desc = ""

        init(description: String) {
            desc = description
        }

        var errorDescription: String? {
            get {
                return self.desc
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks. by the way am try to implement this method i found on exception like this. "Exception writing contacts to vCard (data): A property was not requested when contact was fetched." how to solve?